# How to create launcher icon for android studio in ubuntu 20 LTS?

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu-20.04, android-studio-arctic-fox, launcher-icon

I download **Android Studio - Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1**  from their official website in my ubuntu 20.04 LTS and install via these command:

at first i extract the zip downloaded file to: **/usr/local**
Then i installed via this command : **./studio.sh**
After install, i can not find any desktop launcher icon for android studio.I try to find create desktop entry.But can not found.
Any solution?

Comment: it is not an installer. studio.sh suppose to run android studio, not install it.

Comment: thanks for this information amin

Answer (score 30, accepted):

1. Create or open any project
2. Press `Shift` twice and search "Create desktop entry" under *All* tab

Answer (score 1):

The same problem was caused by writing permission. If you put android dir to usr/local/ with a super user, you must give permission to write to users.

`chmod 775 /usr/local/android-studio/`

After that launch the app, as a normal user with studio.sh, and create a desktop icon again.